# How to add gravity to multiple bodies 'automatically'?

Tags: javascript, game-physics, gravity, rigid-bodies

I know how to add gravity to any given object/element. Just add acceleration Y downwards. But "*what if want my hero to fly?*" or "*what if I want to turn gravity off for one particular object?* I'll have to set `gravity = 0` which will turn off for everyone obviously. I also thought giving every shape their own 'gravity' variable, but I figured that would be too much and it's probably not how it's done...

How would I go from creating shapes

(Using EaseJS)

```
function spawnShape(x, y, w, h) {
    var shape = new createjs.Shape();
    shape.graphics.beginFill("black").drawRect(x, y, w, h);
    stage.addChild(shape);
}

spawnShape(20, 250, 600, 30);
spawnShape(200, 150, 5, 5);

stage.update();
```

to adding gravity "automatically"? (every shape inheriting downwards acceleration) I know there's 2D physics engines made but I want to do/understand this myself, and I did try to use PhysicsJS but failed to do so.. I'll probably be using an engine but for now I want to know how to do this :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object:

```
function Shape(x, y, w, h, gravity){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.gravity = gravity;
    this.shape = new createjs.Shape();
    stage.addChild(shape);
    this.draw = function(){
        shape.graphics.beginFill("black").drawRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

Thus, you can call it as:

```
> x = new Shape(200, 200, 10, 10, 0.5)
Shape {x: 200, y: 200, w: 10, h: 10, gravity: 0.5}
> y = new Shape(400, 100, 50, 100, 0.75)
Shape {x: 400, y: 100, w: 50, h: 100, gravity: 0.75}
> x.gravity = 0
0
> y.gravity
0.75
```

I haven't worked with `EaseJS` so the specifics may be inaccurate but the overarching logic will be as demonstrated above.

Comment: Ok, so I had to ditch the easejs as I couldn't manage to make a method draw using it. This worked `this.draw = function(){ ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h)};`

Answer (score 0):

I think you understand how to add gravity or not add gravity to an object. As you say, it is just adding acceleration Y to the object.

It sounds like you just need to think out your design a little. Let's say you have a module 'gravity.js' that is responsible for applying gravity to an object.

```
/* gravity.js */
const DEFAULT_GRAVITY_ACCELERATION = 1.0;

function applyGravity(shape) {
  const gravity = shape.gravityAcceleration !== undefined ?
    shape.gravityAcceleration : DEFAULT_GRAVITY_ACCELERATION;

  //Do whatever you normally do to update Y acceleration. Code below
  //is just an example.
  shape.addYAcceleration(gravity);
}
```

If you create a shape someplace and want it to be free of gravity, just set the .gravityAcceleration member of that object. BTW, there is nothing special about that "gravityAcceleration" name--it could be whatever you want.

```
//Assuming spawnShape returns an object.
var superman = spawnShape(20, 250, 600, 30); 
superman.gravityAcceleration = 0; //Override the default gravity.
```

You only need to set the .gravityAcceleration member for shape objects that will defy gravity.

Comment: Yeah my bad :|, it was poorly written, in fact I don't know how to work with objects. (I'm very newby :P) but I looked it up a bit and got a better grasp now.